# "High quality" setting when upload image to Google Drive

Tags: images, google-drive, google-photos

I wrote a script to upload images to my Google Drive account. However, the storage space is limited and it'll soon be full if I keep uploading images.

I know that in Google Photo, you have a setting called "High Quality", which will automatically compress your images after they're uploaded, and the space for those "High Quality" images with be unlimited. Is there a way to achieve it with Google Drive? Since images uploaded to Google Drive are showed up on Google Photos as well?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a custom script have you tried the [Google Photo Upload App for Desktop?](https://photos.google.com/apps)

When setting up the app it asks if you would like to choose the High Quality option.

Once uploaded you can then see them in your Drive by selecting "Google Photos" from the left navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: Note that using the app, you cannot organize the Google Photos into folders. It will be organized by year, 2018, 2017, etc. and there's nothing you can do about it. I often have pictures labeled school, profile pictures, friends, etc. but they all get clumped into a year folder.

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe it is possible to store images in Google Drive at original quality. The images will automatically be down-scaled upon upload and Google doesn't currently give you the option to change this.

Not sure why it's like this, but I imagine it's because they really want everyone to adopt Google Photos. It would be nice to see them just combine the two services and get it over with